# How do I send a quantum circuit to IBM for execution?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I have, let's say, the following quantum circuit:

[image]

The QASM code of this quantum scheme has the following form:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[5];
creg c[5];

reset q[0];
reset q[1];
reset q[2];
reset q[3];
reset q[4];
x q[0];
x q[1];
x q[2];
x q[3];
x q[4];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
measure q[2] -> c[2];
measure q[3] -> c[3];
measure q[4] -> c[4];
```

I want to send the QASM code to IBM and get the result. In our case, I want to get `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

I don't understand which endpoints I should send my requests to (probably POST requests) and what I should pass in the message body (in the JSON object).

I was able to execute a GET request to log in and get my access token (access ID). But I don't know what to do next.

There is no complete documentation for the API. [Here is what is available now](https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/v2/).

In what form I would like to see the answer (here I show how to log in and get an access token):

**First step**: *get an access token*.

```
HTTP request method: POST
Endpoint: https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/v2/users/loginWithToken
JSON request:  {
                  "apiToken": "YOUR_API_TOKEN"
               }

JSON response: {
                  "id": "YOUR_ACCESS_ID_TOKEN",
                  "ttl": "YOUR_ACCESS_ID_TOKEN_LIFETIME",
                  "created": "YOUR_ACCESS_ID_TOKEN_CREATIONDATE",
                  "userId": "YOUR_USER_ID"
               }
```

**Second step**: I can't figure out which requests to send next to execute my QASM code and get the result `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: Is using Qiskit an option? If yes sending jobs is a piece of cake :)

Comment: @Cryoris This is really easy to do with Qiskit. But in this study, I need to use the IBM API, which I gave a link to in the question text.

Answer (score 4):

The only API documentation available is the one you linked to. Its [documentation](https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/v2/documentation.html) page describes the steps needed  to submit a job (although not in great details). However, you'll first need to convert your QASM string to a qObject, which is the format the API accepts. Assuming Qiskit is allowed for this part, you can first use [`QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str) to convert the string to a `QuantumCircuit` then use [`assemble()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.assemble.html#qiskit.compiler.assemble) to convert it to a qObject (also called Qobj). If you can't use Qiskit, you'll have to construct the Qobj manually (or using another package that's allowed), following its [schema](https://github.com/Qiskit/ibm-quantum-schemas/blob/main/schemas/qobj_schema.json).

Once you have the Qobj, the steps to submit the job are

1. POST to the `/Network/{hubName}/Groups/{groupName}/Projects/{projectName}/Jobs` endpoint to create a remote job
2. PUT the Qobj to the URL returned by step 1
3. POST to `/Network/{hubName}/Groups/{groupName}/Projects/{projectName}/Jobs/{jobId}/jobDataUploaded` to finish the job submit.

You might want to also take a look at [how it's implemented in Qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/blob/master/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/clients/account.py#L179).